# Storing instances in Laravel Service Container that may be null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-service-container

I'm attempting to store an instance of the current department in Laravels Service Container, however sometimes this department may be `null`.

The department itself is loaded from session and retrieved as such:

```
private function resolveCurrentDepartmentFromSession(Request $request)
{
    $departmentId = $request->session()->pull(self::CURRENT_DEPARTMENT);

    return Department::find($departmentId);
}
```

I store it in the Service Container by:

```
App::instance('Department\Current', $department);
```

And retrieve it as:

```
$department = App::bound('Department\Current') ? App::make('Department\Current') : null;
```

Are there no way to resolve the instance IF set, and return `null` otherwise? Something like `App::instanceIfSet('Department\Current')`? Or should I avoid storing "sometimes null" values in the Service Container? I could make a class `CurrentDepartment` which stores it as a property and store this in the container as a Singleton instead, but would like to know if I'm missing something essential about the Service Container first.

Comment: You might be misusing the service container, why cant you just add a helper to retrieve the department from the session?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `optional` helper:

```
return optional(Department::find($departmentId));
```

Now when you call the bound class any property you attempt to access against it when it is null will also return null.